# Why java consumes about 3GB of memory on the background?

Tags: ubuntu, java, memory-leaks, performance-monitor, background-task

I am just wondering to know what this process stands for and why it consumes that much of memory consistently in my Ubuntu-22.04LTS background?

Is it possible to get ride of it or reduce it's memory consumption?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Please insert text as text, not as an image. // What does your research show? What's the expected workload (which software is installed, what are you doing with it) on this machine?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @DanielB: Unfortunately I can not select the text to copy/paste it. I just installed `Stacer` monitoring app to see what app uses my memory that much and this is what I have found. I don't know what this process is relate to.

Comment: @Community: I just wanted to know if anyone knows what is this process about and what happens if I kill it? Or is there any better application to replace it, etc.

Comment: There are a lot of strings for [Cassandra](https://cassandra.apache.org/_/index.html) amongst your command suggesting that this might well be a database server of some kind. We have no clue what you might be using it for to be able to suggest an alternative. You might be able to [remove cassandra](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48072247/uninstall-cassandra-from-ubuntu) using `sudo apt-get remove cassandra` and see what breaks but only you can say whether that might be a problem.

Comment: @Mokubai: Yeah I just founded out it starts after I run `cassandra` that I think starts it's related service or such a thing in background. Thank you for your help.